# How can i fill the gaps and improve foreground extraction?

Tags: opencv

I want to improve my foreground extraction on my opencv.js project.I am extracting moving foreground from static background.My output foreground have gaps and little bit noisy. How can i fill this gaps with original foreground object color?

Input

[image: Input]

Output

[image: Output]

Here is my code:

```
let video = document.getElementById('videoInput');
let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

let frame = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let fgmask = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
let fgbg = new cv.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(500, 16, false);

const FPS = 30;
function processVideo() {
    try {
        if (!streaming) {
            // clean and stop.
            frame.delete(); fgmask.delete(); fgbg.delete();
            return;
        }
        let begin = Date.now();
        // start processing.
        cap.read(frame);
        fgbg.apply(frame, fgmask);

        frame.copyTo(fgmask, fgmask)    
        cv.imshow('canvasOutput', fgmask);
        // schedule the next one.
        let delay = 1000/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
        setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
    } catch (err) {
        utils.printError(err);
    }
};

// schedule the first one.
setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

apply erosion then dialation to final image, adjust the kernel size and number of iterations to get the best results

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)

erosion = cv.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1)

dilation = cv.dilate(img,kernel,iterations = 1)

Comment: Thank you.I implement erosion and dilation on my code.But it didn't work.
Without Erosion And Dilation : https://streamable.com/xh368                        
With Erosion And Dilation : https://streamable.com/fffsn  
Erosion and Dilation Code:https://anotepad.com/notes/4etr3p

Comment: And ı look at Morphological Transformations documentation.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d76/tutorial_js_morphological_ops.html
 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html
 
I use opening for removing background noise and closing Image for closing
small holes inside the foreground objects.But It didn't work
Without Closing and Opening : https://streamable.com/xh368
 
With Closing and Opening : https://streamable.com/bixmm
 
Closing and Opening Code:https://anotepad.com/notes/e2gbf4