# Smooth foreground extraction

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am trying to do smooth foreground extraction couple of days.I tried many things but nothing seems to work ;( ;(

I just want smooth human body extraction just like this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGMqXBvYxog

1-)I use Morphological Transformations and BackgroundSubstraction to do this.
[Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) says 
"Opening for removing background noise and closing image for closing small holes inside the foreground objects" But It didn't work  ;(

Without Closing and Opening : https://streamable.com/xh368

With Closing and Opening : https://streamable.com/bixmm

Closing and Opening Javascript Code :

```
let video = document.getElementById('videoInput');
let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

let frame = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let fgmask = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
let fgbg = new cv.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(500, 16,false);

const FPS = 30;
function processVideo() {
    try {
        if (!streaming) {
            // clean and stop.
            frame.delete(); fgmask.delete(); fgbg.delete();
            return;
        }
        let begin = Date.now();
        // start processing.
        cap.read(frame);
        fgbg.apply(frame, fgmask); //Apply Background Substraction
        cv.bitwise_not(fgmask,fgmask);//Set background color black and foreground color white for Morphological Transformations
        let M = cv.Mat.ones(5,5, cv.CV_8U); 
        let anchor = new cv.Point(-1, -1);
    cv.morphologyEx(fgmask, fgmask, cv.MORPH_OPEN, M, anchor, 1,
        cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, cv.morphologyDefaultBorderValue());
    cv.morphologyEx(fgmask,fgmask, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, M);
        frame.copyTo(fgmask, fgmask);   //Copy original colors
        cv.imshow('canvasOutput', fgmask);
        // schedule the next one.
        let delay = 100/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
        setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
    } catch (err) {
        utils.printError(err);
    }
};

// schedule the first one.
setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
```

Full HTML:https://anotepad.com/notes/ne7n4w

All files:https://files.fm/u/c9egsgqe

2-))I am using haarcascades to extract human bodies in this technique , just like this:https://www.bytefish.de/blog/extracting_contours_with_opencv/

This algorithm run on following 5 steps.These algorithm not work very well because sometimes haar cascades cannot detect objects
Javascript Code

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let gray = new cv.Mat();
cv.cvtColor(src, gray, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
let faces = new cv.RectVector();
let poly=new cv.MatVector();
let faceCascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
faceCascade.load('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
let msize = new cv.Size(0, 0);
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.1, 3, 0, msize, msize);


//1-Create a mask with the rectangular coordinates
let rect = new cv.Rect(faces.get(0).x, faces.get(0).y,faces.get(0).width,faces.get(0).height);

//2-Mask out
dst = src.roi(rect);

//3-Edge detection using canny 
let cannyoutput=new cv.Mat();
cv.Canny(dst, cannyoutput, 0, 100, 3, true);

//4-Find contours
let contours = new cv.MatVector();
let hierarchy = new cv.Mat(); 
cv.findContours(cannyoutput,contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_CCOMP, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

//cv.drawContours(); 


cv.imshow('canvasOutput', cannyoutput);
src.delete(); gray.delete(); faceCascade.delete();
faces.delete(); 
contours.delete(); hierarchy.delete();
```

3-)I tried to apply erosion then dialatios ,it didn't work.[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809225/how-can-i-fill-the-gaps-and-improve-foreground-extraction)

Without Erosion And Dilation : https://streamable.com/xh368

With Erosion And Dilation : https://streamable.com/fffsn

My javascript code:

```
let video = document.getElementById('videoInput');
let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

let frame = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let fgmask = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
let fgbg = new cv.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(500, 16,false);

const FPS = 30;
function processVideo() {
    try {
        if (!streaming) {
            // clean and stop.
            frame.delete(); fgmask.delete(); fgbg.delete();
            return;
        }
        let begin = Date.now();
        // start processing.
        cap.read(frame);
        fgbg.apply(frame, fgmask);
        cv.bitwise_not(fgmask,fgmask);  
        let M = cv.Mat.ones(5,5, cv.CV_8U); 
        let anchor = new cv.Point(-1, -1);
        cv.erode(fgmask, fgmask, M, anchor, 1, 
        cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, cv.morphologyDefaultBorderValue());
        cv.dilate(fgmask, fgmask, M, anchor, 1, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, 
        cv.morphologyDefaultBorderValue());
        frame.copyTo(fgmask, fgmask);   
        cv.imshow('canvasOutput', fgmask);
        // schedule the next one.
        let delay = 1000/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
        setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
    } catch (err) {
        utils.printError(err);
    }
};

// schedule the first one.
setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
```

My full html:https://anotepad.com/notes/gg5esk

Comment: I think you stumbled upon the reason a green screen is used.  

Can you try to do your video in front of an uniform coloured background and see what the results are with that?

Comment: Thank you.I try this and get a very well output     https://imgur.com/a/Or6St                                       
 but in the real world nothing is in front of an uniform coloured background.

Comment: Yup, and that's why there exist very expensive video editing software packages, where everything gets traced, outlined and carefully edited and corrected frame by frame in complex situations. It's a lot of work, which has a lot of manual correction labour in it, even in this day and age. There is no magical "flip flop" to automatically outline moving images yet that works flawlessly on any background and any lighting condition.

Comment: When I  starting image-processing, I thought big: a general background remover that will automatically identify the foreground and background in every type of image.Now I think this is imposibble.Maybe , is machine learning useful to extract human body foreground?

Comment: simple MOG Backgroundsubtraction is a quite limited technique. Deep Learning or HoG for example can be used to detect upper body, but typically you won't get a fine segmentation. If you still try to improve your MOG code, you could give superpixel segmentation a try.